# Android, How to add icon in TabButton in my code

Tags: android, android-widget

Here i make 5 Tab buttons that are working proper but now i want to add icon with each Tab, How to add tab icon respect to Tab buttons.... Please guide/help me..

i am using stackOverflow first time please tell if here i missed any steps while posting this code...
Thanks in advance

```
package com.vishesh.soapbox;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Start extends TabActivity {
private TabHost tabHost;
//Resources res=getResources();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    //textView for signout from application 
    TextView signout=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.signout);
    signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();   
        }
    });

    // scan button use for read the BarCode through RedLaser
    Button scan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
    final Intent intent=new Intent(this,RLSample.class);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //for Tab button

    tabHost=getTabHost();
    setupTabhost();

    Intent intent1=new Intent().setClass(this, SoapBox.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this),"SoapBox", intent1);
    Intent intent2=new Intent().setClass(this, Profile.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this),"Profile", intent2);
    Intent intent3=new Intent().setClass(this, Challenges.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this),"Challenges", intent3);
    Intent intent4=new Intent().setClass(this, Vault.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this),"Vault", intent4);
    Intent intent5=new Intent().setClass(this, More.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this),"More", intent5);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
    private void setupTabhost()
    {
        tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
    }
    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Intent intent)
    {
        View tabView=createTabView(tabHost.getContext(),tag);
        TabSpec tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabView).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text)
    {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.start_tabs_bg, null);
        TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        textView.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vishesh,

If you look at the example [HERE](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)...

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
```

The `drawable` icon is passed in the call to `setIndicator()`.  And you could replace both "Albums" strings with your `tag` variable.

Although, it currently looks like you are using a custom View for your tabs.  You would just have to add an `ImageView` to the layout and set the `drawable` to the icon you desire.

Comment: Actually when i putting "setIndicator(tabView, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);" inside the setIndicator then i got one error "The method setIndicator(CharSequence, Drawable) in the type TabHost.TabSpec is not applicable for the arguments (View, Drawable) "

Comment: did you declare `res`?  Try `Resources res = getResources();`

Comment: Instead of passing the `View`, pass your `tag` variable.

Comment: 'code' setIndicator(tabView, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);

Comment: if i am changing there then i am getting "NullPointerexception".

Comment: `setIndicator(tag, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);` does not work for you?

Comment: do you actually have an `icon.png` image in your `/drawable` folder?  just try `R.drawable.ic_tab_albums` in `getDrawable()` and see if that works...

Comment: 06-08 19:50:41.704: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.skynex.soapbox/com.skynex.soapbox.Start}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i changed that icon image but again getting same NullPointerException in LogCat

Comment: tell me one thing please, How to change the Tab background color when selected, pressed, unselected, after that this problem will be easy for me..

Comment: ohhh I'm sorry.  That drawable is part of the example program.  Try an built in icon like `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add`.

Comment: thanks for all discussion, please tell me How to change the Tab background color when selected, pressed, unselected, after that this problem will be easy for me..... Thanks

Comment: you will probably need a StateListDrawable: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList